# Keycloak pass data from one custom authentication to another

Tags: freemarker, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have created three custom authenticators for register flow each validate separate pages(ftl file) data. How to pass a data from one authenticator to another?

If I use `session.setAttribute()` that value will be removed if user refresh the page. How to persist previous page value to continue a flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `context.getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote(key,value)` to persist a value

Comment: This will allow to set only on string value  agains key so if anyone want to store object then how to set and get it?

Comment: @PiyushChaudhari you can always serialize the object I guess